# Z3py - do a roll

Tags: python, z3, smt

Is there a recommended way of doing a bitwise roll to either left or right by any amount?

For example with a byte - `0x57 rolr 3 = 0xEA`.

I have not found any "roll" operation in the Z3py docs.  I was thinking about using a `BitVec`s for each bit but that doesn't seem efficient/probably won't work. Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

Edit: Thanks for the answers so far.  This is more of an API question because I suck at it right now.  Heres what I have as a starting point.

```
def roll(bt):
count = BitVecVal(int('0x03', 16), 8)
s.add(bt == (bt << count | bt >> (8 - count)) & 0xFF)

a = BitVec('a', 8)
s = Solver()
roll(a)
s.add(a == BitVecVal(int('0xEA', 16), 8))
s.check()
```

This prints out nothing and model is not available.

Comment: What is different from a [shift](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types)?

Comment: `>>` is the arithmetical shift. That is why it does not work. Here is a link with an example: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/5NwMR

Comment: BTW, Z3Py has functions: `RotateLeft` and `RotateRight`. The z3.py module has a bunch of pydoc annotations. Here is the online API reference guide produced by doxygen: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/namespacez3py.html

Comment: @LeonardodeMoura This code doesn't print out anything, is something not right?
`a = BitVec('a', 8)`
`s = Solver()`
`s.add(RotateLeft(a, 3) == BitVecVal(int('0xEA', 16), 8))`
`s.check()`
`s.model()`

Comment: You have to add `print`. Here is the link for your examples with the `print`s: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/v6D

Answer (score 2):

You can do a rotate like this:

```
size = 0x100  # size of the bitvector

rotated = (x << n) | (x >> (size - n)) & (size - 1)
```

Comment: Eric, your solution is almost correct. The problem is that `>>`, in Z3Py, is the arithmetical shift. For the logical shift we have to use the function `LShR`. We can try it online http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/kpd1

Comment: @LeonardodeMoura: hence the `& (size - 1)` at the end. Trying what I wrote in my answer: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/K58

Comment: @LeonardodeMoura: Actually, I have no idea why this code works. Won't `(x >> (size - n))` fill all the high bits with 1s if the top bit of x is set?

Comment: Eric: You are correct, the `(x >> (size - n))` will fill the high bits with 1s. That is, why I said it was incorrect. We can erase the high bits by doing the bitwise-and with `((1 << n) - 1)`. This will erase all but the first `n` bits. The bitwise-and with `(size - 1)` only works when `((1 << n) - 1) == (size - 1)`. That is indeed the case for `n == 5` and `size == 32`. Here is the link for the general version: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/g127

Comment: @LeonardodeMoura: I have no idea what I was thinking there. When I wrote `(size - 1)`, what I meant was `(1 << size - 1)`, with the intent of masking out overflowing bits.